# Modularizing class-level method calls by evaluating them in `included` methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I'm working with a Rails project that uses the [flip gem](https://github.com/pda/flip#declaring-features) for feature flags. We have a Feature class in which you can declare the various feature flags you want to use,

```
# app/models/feature.rb

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend   Flip::Declarable
  strategy Flip::DeclarationStrategy

  feature :ivans_feature_A
  feature :ivans_feature_B
  feature :ivans_feature_C

  feature :kramers_feature_X
  feature :kramers_feature_X
end
```

As the project grows, so does the number of feature-flags we've got declared in this file. A coworker suggested we break related feature-declarations into separate modules to organize things.

I've found a way to do this, but it's not a pattern I've seen used before so I wonder if there's a more standard way. I'm defining namespaced modules for each bunch of features I want to group together:

app/models/features/ivans_features.rb

```
module Features::IvansFeatures
  def self.included(base)
    base.feature :ivans_feature_A
    base.feature :ivans_feature_B
    base.feature :ivans_feature_C
  end
end
```

app/models/features/kramers_features.rb

```
module Features::KramersFeatures
  def self.included(base)
    base.feature :kramers_feature_X
    base.feature :kramers_feature_Y
  end
end
```

...and including them in the feature model:

```
# app/models/feature.rb

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend   Flip::Declarable
  strategy Flip::DeclarationStrategy

  include  Features::IvansFeatures
  include  Features::KramersFeatures
end
```

Is it strange to mix a module into a class for the sole purpose of usingthe `included` callback to run some method calls on the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Feature` class you can `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` and then do something like

```
included do
  feature :kramers_feature_X
end
```